# What's the difference between the two ways that contract B interacts with contract A?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, abi

The deployed contract A:

A.sol：

```
contract A {
    function testA() public returns(uint) {return 1;};
}
```

Here is the first way that contract B interacts with contract A:

B.sol:

```
import "./A.sol";

contract B {
    A a;
    function testB() public returns(uint) {
        a.testA();
    }
}
```

Here is the second way that contract B interacts with contract A:

IA.sol:

```
interface IA {
    function testA() external returns(uint) {};
}
```

B.sol:

```
import "./IA.sol";

contract B {
    IA a = IA(addressOfA);
    function testB() public returns(uint) {
        a.testA();
    }
}
```

**Question:**

What's the difference between the two ways? I know the second way is the way that how contract interacts with another deployed contract (know its address and ABI), but What does the first way mean? Why can the first way also work? What's the first way used for?

Comment: The first option will always revert, because `a` is not initialized.

Comment: The second option will not even compile, because you cannot declare a `public` function in an `interface`, and even more so - you can definitely not implement a function in an interface (that's why it's called "interface").

Comment: Adding the interface wrapping into your question just makes it more confusing than it already is. The difference is between constructing the `A` contract internally via `A a = new A()`, and creating a pointer to it via `A a = A(someAddress)`. I mean, that's how your question should be asked.

Comment: I have modified the IA.sol. What shoud I do to initialize ```a``` in the first option?

Comment: Did you read my comment above? It answers that exactly.

Comment: for ```A a = new A()```, ```a``` is the instance of a new contract with new address. for the first option, I just wanna use testA() of contract A in the contract B, what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean "contract A in the contract B"???

Comment: the example from the official doc: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.3/control-structures.html#external-function-calls
why could it work? instead of implementing the interface of contract ```InfoFeed``` firstly, and then in the contract ```Consumer```: ```IInfoFeed feed = IInfoFeed(addressOfInfoFeed)```

Comment: How exactly does that answer what I just asked???

Comment: In short, before we get into more of these futile comments, you must initialize `a` in order to use it. BTW, note that this statement is true **for every variable in every language**. In your case, you can either initialize it to point to an already deployed contract via `A a = A(deployedContractAddress)`, or to point to a newly deployed contract via `A a = new A()`.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89411/whats-the-difference-between-the-two-ways-of-calling-the-function-of-another-co